# Allowing at most 2 newline in textarea

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, preg-replace

I want to allow at most 2 newline characters in a text area.
I want this solution in PHP or in PHP+JavaScript/jQuery.
When ever the users enter more than 2 newline they will be replaced by 2 newline characters.

The Input:

```
0
1

2


3



4
```

whatever i tried and failed

```
<html>
<form name="f" method="post">
1 <textarea name="t">
<?php
if (isset($_POST['t']))
{
 $t2 = $_POST['t'];
 $t3 = $_POST['t'];
 $t4 = $_POST['t'];
 echo $_POST['t'];
}
?>
</textarea>
<br>
2 <textarea name="t2">
<?php
if (isset($_POST['t']))
{
 $t2 = preg_replace('/\s*$^\s*/m', "\n", $t2);
 echo preg_replace('/[ \t]+/', ' ', $t2);
}
?>
</textarea>
<br>
3 <textarea name="t3">
<?php
if (isset($_POST['t']))
{
 $t3 = preg_replace("/[\n]+/m", "\n\n", $t3);
 //$t3 = preg_replace("/[\r\n]+/m", "\n", $t3);
 $t3 = preg_replace("/[\t]+/m", "\t", $t3);
 $t3 = preg_replace("/[  ]+/m", " ", $t3);
 //$t3 = preg_replace("/\s+/", ' ', $t3);
 echo $t3;
}
?>
</textarea>
<br>
4 <textarea name="t4">
<?php
if (isset($_POST['t']))
{
 //$t4 = preg_replace('/[\n\r]{2,}/', "\n\n", $t4);
 $t4 = preg_replace( "\r\n\r\n([\r\n]+)", "\r\n\r\n", $t4);
 echo $t4;
}
?>
</textarea>
<input type="submit">
</form>
</html>
```

Comment: And if the user's sneaky and does `\n<space>\n<space>\n<space>\n<tab>\n` and so on?

Comment: i hate sneaky users :x, btw you got any solution for the problem ? If yes, please share ! I badly need it

Answer (score 2):

Just do `$subject = preg_replace('/\n{2,}/', "\n\n", $subject);` That will catch two or more newlines and replace it with two newlines.

**edit**

If you wanted to be safer you might change the pattern to `/[\n\r]{2,}/` to catch carriage returns as well but I think it's unnecessary.

Comment: Did you try changing the 2 to a 3?

Comment: I just tried the code and it worked fine. Perhaps a `<br/>` is being passed in and not a newline. The code works for the problem specified.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$data = "whatever data with \r\n\r\n\r\n more than \r\n two lines \r\n\r\n example";
$fixed_data = preg_replace( "\r\n\r\n([\r\n]+)", "\r\n\r\n", $data);
echo $fixed_data;
// should output: whatever data with \r\n\r\n more than \r\n two lines \r\n\r\n example
```

The above regex replacement should look for two new lines (with an optional infinite as many new lines) and replace them all with 2 new lines.

:)

Comment: it allows at most 1 newline in FF 3.6

Comment: Edit: Check and see if the $t3 or $t4 contains `\r\n` and not just `\n`. It will impact the regex statement if it doesn't contain a `\r`.

Comment: What is the input and output of $t4?

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = preg_replace('/(\r?\n){3,}/',"\n\n",$data);
```