# Allow at most 3 consecutive whitespaae charecters

Tags: javascript, trim

I'll get some info from an user using textarea. But he can not type 3 consecutive white space characters, so i invested this code :D

```
function trim(myString)
{
 str = myString;
 str = str.replace(/\s/g, " ");
 alert(str.lastIndexOf("   "));
 if (str.lastIndexOf("   ")>-1)
 {
  alert("At most 3 consecutive white Space is allowed !");
  return false;
 }
 return myString.replace(/^[\s]+/,'').replace(/[\s]+$/,'').replace(/[\s]{2,}/,' ');
}
```

but it does not work, can you help me correcting the error ?

The above code first replaces all types of white characters with a space, then it search for 3 consecutive white space, if it founds then it shows an alert !

You can also have a look at [Allowing at most 2 newline in textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6475592)

Comment: What doesn't work? What happens?

Comment: what issue are you exactly having with this code?

Comment: it does not work the way it should do, it always keep saying AT MOST .... :x

Comment: Do you want to just alert the user, or both alert and remove whitespace sequences longer than 3?

Comment: You are a bit inconsistent; you say that at most 3 spaces are allowed, but you alert the user if the string contains exactly 3 (which should be allowed).

Comment: @Anders Fjeldstad I'm wrong, thats the reason to come to SO and asking for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with this alternative, simplified version:

```
 function trim(str)
 {
      if (str.match(/\s\s\s+/))
      {
           alert("At most 3 consecutive white Space is allowed !");
           return false;
      }
     return str.replace(/\s\s\s+/g,' ');
 }
```

Comment: That replaces 3+ whitespace chars with one, which means 'a   b' (3 spaces) turns into 'a b' (1 space).

Comment: Note this will only check for the first occurrence of three spaces, the user input could well have multiple occurrences.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should reconsider your design - it's a bit confusing to have a `trim` method that returns `false` for some argument values and a string for others. How about just removing any whitespace characters that are "not allowed"? Then your method could be rewritten as:

```
function trim(myString) {
    return myString.replace(/^\s+/,'').replace(/\s+$/,'').replace(/\s{3,}/,'   ');
}
```

First, leading and trailing whitespace is removed, then all sequences of 3 or more whitespace characters are replaced by 3 spaces. For example:

```
var str = ' a    b   c  d e      ';
trim(str); // Returns 'a   b   c  d e'
```

Note: [in modern browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim), the function could be simplified further:

```
function trim(myString) {
    return myString.trim().replace(/\s{3,}/,'   ');
}
```